# Atom::PlatformIO IDE, can't get `send selected text to terminal` to work

Tags: atom-editor

I just installed PlatformIO IDE (IDE 1.2.2 | CLI 2.9.4).

I can toggle a terminal and type commands in it and they would work.

However, when I select text and press `ctrl-enter`, it is not send to the terminal. I tried to change the key bindings to something else but that didn't solve the problem. 
My question is what to try next? (I have the same problem in both Fedora 23 and Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## open your keymap

ctrl + shif + p , search keymap, & enter

## add platform-ide key map

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
    'ctrl-enter': 'platformio-ide-terminal:insert-selected-text'
```